# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.test,myapp/com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity}

Tags: android, google-map-place

As per [google intimation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) I have recently migrate new Places SDK. After that unable to navigate AutocompleteActivity. below is my starting Activity call.

```
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.values());
 Intent autocompleteIntent =
                new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                        .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(autocompleteIntent, 101);
```

this my gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.test.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 52
    versionName "4.2"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
   }
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':appupdater')
implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:$rootProject.commonCodecVersion"
implementation "com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:$rootProject.volleyVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.googlePlayServiceVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.googlePlayServiceVersion"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'

implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
implementation "me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:$rootProject.zxingVersion"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

configurations{
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
    }
}
```

Whenever I have call that starting AutocompleteActivity i got below exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.test.myapp/com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized.
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.go.b(PG:22)
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity.onCreate(PG:2)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

I hope AutocompleteActivity no need to include in Manifeast.

Comment: Did you initialized the Places SDK with Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey); ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have missed that one. Added now working good. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Welcome, I have updated the answer, so others are also able to find the solution. :) Also, don't forget to up vote :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialized the Places SDK with Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);